# Issues making use of money.js with accounting.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, currency, money.js

I'd like to make use of [money.js](http://josscrowcroft.github.io/money.js/) and [accounting.js](http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/) (for formatting currencies) to change the currency of a given price. I'd first like to get a simple example working before going any further.

[This article](http://www.solidshops.com/blog/how-tos/tutorial-currency-conversion-made-easy-with-money-js-accounting-js/) describes exactly what I'd like to accomplish, so I tried replicating it's example, however, I'm having some difficulty getting it to work.

I would like to replace the JSON from [openexchangerates.org](http://openexchangerates.org) in the article with [fixer.io](http://api.fixer.io/latest) (which is based of the [European Central Bank's feed](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html)).

Here's what it looks like so far, which is basically what the article linked above consists of - http://jsfiddle.net/d6f5a/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  fx.base = "EUR";
  fx.settings = {
    from : "EUR"
  };

  var amount = 9.99;
  // Load exchange rates data via the cross-domain/AJAX proxy:

  $.getJSON(
      'http://api.fixer.io/latest',
      function(data) {
          // Check money.js has finished loading:
          if ( typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates ) {
              fx.rates = data.rates;
              fx.base = data.base;
          } else {
              // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
              var fxSetup = {
                  rates : data.rates,
                  base : data.base
              }
          }

         // now that we have exchange rates, add a few to our page
         var USD = fx.convert(amount, {to: "USD"}); //13.22784197768393
         var GBP = fx.convert(amount, {to: "GBP"}); //8.567532636985659
         var JPY = fx.convert(amount, {to: "JPY"}); //1028.1670562349989

         // use the accounting.js library to format the numbers properly
         USD = accounting.formatMoney(USD, "$ ", 2, ",", ".");
         GBP = accounting.formatMoney(GBP, "£ ", 2, ",", ".");
         JPY = accounting.formatMoney(JPY, "¥ ", 2, ",", ".");

         $("ul.currencies").append("<li>USD estimate: " + USD + "</li>");
         $("ul.currencies").append("<li>GBP estimate: " + GBP + "</li>");
         $("ul.currencies").append("<li>JPY estimate: " + JPY + "</li>");
      }
  );
});
```

Any help or pointers would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After further digging, I found out that the issue was related to Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

To such an extent, the browser was not loading the JSON file, and therefore, the script was failing. In order to get around this I set the JSON URL to `http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP,JPY**&callback=?**`

By making use of ?callback=?, or &callback=?, jQuery would making a JSON-P request to the API.

I've updated my example here - http://jsfiddle.net/d6f5a/3/